# Rewrite a domain in mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I have an Android app, which is making request to example.com.
How can I setup mitmproxy such that all requests to example.com/etc/else will go to dev.example.com/etc/else?

I tried this:

My script (rewrite.py):

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers

def request(context, flow):
    if 'example.com' in flow.request.url :
        flow.request.host = 'dev.example.com'
```

Also, for some reason I don't see logging output, for example:

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
 ...
ctx.log.info("This is some informative text.")
```

I'm running mitmproxy like this:

```
mitmproxy -p 8765 -e -s rewrite.py
```

Comment: Which version of mitmproxy are you running? What happens if you run the same with mitmdump?

Comment: @MaximilianHils my version is 0.18.2. Same with mitmdump just prints me CONNECT example.com:443, but not dev.example.com

Comment: In addition `def request(context, flow)` needs only one argument, so I left it with `def request(flow)`

Comment: Yes - we simplified the API with 0.18 in that regard; albeit there is a very unfortunate bug that silences loading errors. https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/0.18.x/examples/redirect_requests.py works fine for me - if you are still running into issues, please feel to just ping me in the mitmproxy slack for quicker turnaround times. Happy to update this here with a solution afterwards. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with mitmproxy v0.18.2 the solution is:

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers
from mitmproxy import ctx

def request( flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_host.endswith('example.com'):
        flow.request.host = 'dev.example.com'
        flow.request.scheme = 'http'
        flow.request.port = 80
        ctx.log.info(" --->" + flow.request.url)
```

Comment: You can exclude:
`from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse`
and
`from netlib.http import Headers`